# Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that if $G$ has exactly one nontrivial subgroup, then order of $G$ is $p^2$ for some prime $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that if $G$ has exactly one nontrivial subgroup, then order of $G$ is $p^2$ for some prime $p$.

---

I am totally clueless for this problem.Can someone help me to solve the problem.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First of all, show that there are not primes $p\neq q$ such that $p||G|$ and $q||G|$ simultaneously. And then conclude that $|G|=p^n$ for some positive integer $n$ and finally try to make a contradiction by assuming $n\ge3$.

Comment: We love our groups, don't we ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Yes they are but the semi ones are absolutely incorrigible. :(

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the first [Sylow theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorem).